# Update app with new name or do I need to submit a new app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

I submitted an app to the app store, but a few weeks later we decided to change the name of our app. Can we simply upload a new version of the app with changes to the metadata or do we need to go through the entire submission process again with Apple?

And by metadata, I'm basically referring to title, keywords, descriptions, and screenshots. All of these should match the new name.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id{yourAppId}

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a new app for that, but you need to submit a new build of existing app to make these changes. After adding a new version in iTunes connect, you can change the app name, keywords and other meta-data information there.

Comment: My developer is telling me that you can't change the name of the app that is attached to an ID for the store.

He also says that every project created on xcode is attached to a domain, which is the name of the app. That can't just be renamed because there is obscure code created by xcode that contains the domain name and will make the app crash when calling OS services for the device.

Comment: @GabrielRotman: No, that is not true. You can't change the bundle id, but you can change the app name. I had an app in App Store, I named it like **myappLite** (Not original name), I forgot to add space and had naming issues. So in next release I changed the name to **MyApp Lite**. So I have experience renaming the app, so I'm 100% sure that you can change the name of your app. Only thing is you need to add a new version to edit the metadata.

Comment: @GabrielRotman: You can refer this apple document for better clarification https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html

Comment: Thank you Midhun. In your example the names are very similar. In our example, the names are very different (i.e. ABC changed to XYZ). The domain is different too as a result. Our brand changed, so we will need to make sure that the links and metadata match the new name and domain. Does this change your perspective on the situation?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very broad and ... it depends.

- If your app was called ABC and it was never published on the app store and you wanted to change the name to be completely different like XYZ then you need to change metadata to XYZ in itunesconnect and you also need to change the bundle display name in your info.plist file, repackage / archive the binary, re-upload to itunes to reflect the new name "XYZ". If you don't do that then the lords will reject your app.
- If your app was "ABC - great app" and you decided to change the name to "ABC - super duper" app, as long as the installed name of the app was "ABC", you don't need to do anything other than just change name in itunesconnect.

Comment: To clarify, the app was named ABC and changing it to a completely different name like XYZ.